# More than one collection not working anymore in Google Drive?

Tags: google-docs-api, google-drive-api

We use extensively (from an application) in the Document List API the fact than a file / document can be assigned to more than one collection, in order to work in a similar way that labels. Has this been deprecated? At least from the web user interface, only one folder can be assigned to one file.

Answer (score 1):

Working fine here and multiple collections can be successfully assigned.

Right click a file, Choose "Organise" and check the box next to each collection you want the document to be a part of.

Comment: It's necessary to hold CTRL+click in order to select more than one folder.

If a file is in two folders, is syncronized, copied twice in PC (Sorry I use Linux and still I have not tested PC client)